# 'functions' is assigned a value but never used

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am getting an error in terminal when trying to run 'firebase deploy'. This brings the error

```
1:7  error  'functions' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

here is my index.js file

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into 
// Firestore under the path /messages/:documentId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
// Grab the text parameter.
const original = req.query.text;
// Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
// Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
});

// Listens for new messages added to /messages/:documentId/original and creates an
// uppercase version of the message to /messages/:documentId/uppercase
exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
 // Grab the current value of what was written to Firestore.
 const original = snap.data().original;

 // Access the parameter `{documentId}` with `context.params`
 functions.logger.log('Uppercasing', context.params.documentId, original);

 const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();

 // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
 // writing to Firestore.
 // Setting an 'uppercase' field in Firestore document returns a Promise.
return snap.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
});
```

this is directly from the firebase functions documentation

[image]

Comment: This error returned by `eslint` interrupted the deployment; is the `"no-unused-vars": "error"` enabled in the `eslintrc.json`?

Comment: Where would I find this file?m In node_modules?

Comment: check under `functions` folder..

Comment: You shall try deployment by setting the `"no-unused-vars": "off"`.

Comment: eslintrc.json does not exist all I have is firebase-debug.log, index.js, node_modules, package-lock.json, package.json

Comment: What file do you suggest I implement this code into? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: if you don't want eslint now, you can disable it by editing your `firebase.json` file and removing the predeploy script that runs the lint command.

Comment: I am more interested in solving this problem than working around it for it to be solved later

Comment: The .eslintrc.json file is hidden, maybe double check you really don't have it in [the functions directory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). Otherwise, you can create it.

Answer (score 0):

Your index file is outside the functions folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just added warning instead of error in the rules at the

.eslintrc.js file

```
rules: {
   
    "no-unused-vars": "warn"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap any block of code with eslint specific comments to disable a rule for that block:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
(....Your Code....)
/* eslint-enable no-unused-vars */
```

this way you need not to comment your pre-deploy script checks
and you can disable the enlint properties for the selected block

Comment: Tried this still had the same error

Answer (score 0):

In firebase.json, delete these 3 lines :

```
"predeploy": [
    "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
  ]
```

In functions folder/package.json, delete these lines :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.9.0", // delete
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0", // delete
  }
 "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .", // delete 
  },
```

Delete node_modules in function folder then reinstall all with npm install (you must be in the function folder)

Then : firebase deploy will work fine

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get around it was the temporary solution of going into the firebase.json file and removing the predeploy script.

Comment: I believe I just changed `"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",  
  },` to `"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint", 
  },` in the `package.json` file which is typically located in the firebase functions folder usually named `functions`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what I think is causing the issue in the majority of cases here. People have their `index.js` file in the wrong place.

What this means is that they are happily editing it to try to fix the issue without realising that *eslint* isn't looking at the `index.js` file they created, but instead the default one automatically generated within the `functions` folder. This default `index.js` file will experience this bug until it is fixed.